# There is no proper subgroup of $\mathbb Q$ of finite index

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to show that there is no proper subgroup of $\mathbb Q$ of finite index.

I found many solutions using quotient group idea.

But I didn't learn about that. So I want to solve it without using that.

For example I solve [$\mathbb{Q}:\mathbb{Z}$] is infinite like this.

Suppose $[\mathbb{Q}:\mathbb{Z}$] is finite.

Then $\exists a_1, \ldots , a_n $ s.t. $ \mathbb{Q} = \bigcup_{i=1}^n (a_i+ \mathbb{Z}) $

WLOG, 0$\le a_1, \ldots , a_n \lt $1

Since $\mathbb{Q} $ is dense, $\exists 0\le r \lt 1$ s.t $ r\neq a_i $ for each i.

Then $r\in \mathbb{Q} $ but $r\notin \bigcup_{i=1}^n (a_i+ \mathbb{Z})$, contradiction.

Can I solve my question likewise?

Answer (score 5):

Let us assume that $A$ is a subqroup of $\mathbb{Q}$ of finite index n, and $\phi:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}/A$ be a natural homomorphism. Then $|\mathbb{Q}/A|=n$, hence $n\phi(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, i.e $nx\in A$ for all $x\in \mathbb{Q}$. Now let $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ be any rational. Then $x=n(x/n)\in A$, so $x\in A$ and $A=\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Good, and better than what I was trying to cook up.

Comment: "I found many solutions using quotient group idea. But I didn't learn about that. So I want to solve it without using that."

Comment: @user26857 these words appeared later )

Comment: @user26857 How do you even define the index without defining the quotient?

Comment: @AlexW The history of this question shows that the words were there from the very beginning. (Even in the case they weren't there - but they were! - I think your answer doesn't answer the question as it is now.)

Comment: @user26857 perhaps I read the question inattentively, but people like)

Comment: @user26857 Hm, I see. So just the quotient set but not the quotient group.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Yes, and it seems that the OP wants to find out if can get that (in)finite index property by using only some set properties as he did for $H=\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @AlexW T_T I can't understand.. I just know index and concept of coset, Lagrange's theorem.